# Angular ngFor spanning two rows (expand/collapse)

Tags: angular, html-table, expand, ngfor

I have an angular application. I need display a list of data in a table. I have applied ngFor on the TR element of the table. However, when each row is expanded, another row with additional details about the item must be displayed.

Collapsed view:
[image]

Expanded view:
[image]

Code:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>Header here</tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of results">
      + Collapsed Row
      <!-- How do I display the expanded row and display additional details when + symbol is clicked? -->
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you just want a simple expand and collapse row, then a simple `ngIf` will do the trick:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of results">
  <div (click)="item.expanded=!item.expanded">+ Collapsed Row</div>
  <span *ngIf="item.expanded">This is an expanded content</span>
</tr>
```

However, if you want to have only one row to be expanded at a time, then you need to keep track on which row is expanded.

In your html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of results; let $index=index;">
  <div (click)="expandRow($index)">+ Collapsed Row</div>
  <span *ngIf="$index === expandedIndex">This is an expanded content</span>
</tr>
```

In your component, initialize a variable called `expandedIndex` with the value of -1. This ensures all rows are collapsed when the component is inited. You can do it either at constructor level or at `ngOnInit`, it doesn't really matter:

```
constructor(public expandedIndex:number){
   this.expandedIndex=-1;
}
```

Then, have a named function called `expandRow`:

```
  expandRow(index: number): void {
    this.expandedIndex = index === this.expandedIndex ? -1 : index;
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Div and Span do render within a TR but the tabular structure is lost. I basically need two TRs (repeated), one of which is visible/hidden based on a condition. And inside those TRs, I need TDs.

Comment: No, you can't. You can't have a two `tr` repeated twice, futhermore hide and show then based on a single repeated instance's condition. Either you change your css (if that's your concern), or you willn have to dynamically change the content inside the single `tr`

Comment: This would be great. If `<tr>` could have `<div>` or `<span>` as direct children....

Answer (score 2):

I faced it the same problem and i didn't find any good solution. But after a deep reseach i found this ng-container and it worked very well. U can see it in action bellow

https://plnkr.co/edit/F8ohXKLHvvbHXAqGESQN?p=preview

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of posts">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button (click)="openCloseRow(obj.id)">
                        <span *ngIf="rowSelected!=obj.id; else close">Open</span>
                          <ng-template #close>
                            <span>Close</span>
                            </ng-template>
                    </button>
                </td> 
              <td>{{obj.date}}</td>
              <td>
                  {{obj.subject}}
              </td>
              <td>{{obj.numComents}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="rowSelected==obj.id">
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                                   
                                <th style="width:15%;">Comment</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let q of obj.comments">                                  
                                <td style="width:15%;">{{q}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes, this works file, because ng-container does not create additional HTML tag